# How to remove repeated foreach values in jquery

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working now wordpress this is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 <?php
 $var= $product->get_available_variations();
 foreach ($var as $key => $test)
 {

$check=$test['display_price'];
 ?>
 var check='<?php echo $check;?>';              

 jQuery('<p>'+check+'</p>').appendTo('.variation_buttons_wrapper');

 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Actually my task is split foreach values and append another div.But my answer is again and again repeated.My out put is there,

```
53.95
39.95
29.95
27.95
53.95
39.95
29.95
27.95
53.95
39.95
29.95
27.95
53.95
39.95
29.95
27.95
```

But i want out put

```
 53.95
39.95
29.95
27.95
```

this only.please help me.

Comment: if possible try $result = array_unique($var); before foreach which can remove duplicate.

Comment: ya! i am using  $var= array_unique($product->get_available_variations());
But i get answer    53.95 is repeated 4 time and 39.95,29.95,27.95      this all missing

Comment: $product->get_available_variations() how many variation are there

Comment: 4 variation is there

Comment: My code is there                                                                                            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

<?php
$var= array_unique($product->get_available_variations());

foreach ($var as $key => $test)
{

$check=$test['display_price'];
?>
var check='<?php echo $check;?>';    

jQuery('<p>'+check+'</p>').appendTo('.variation_buttons_wrapper');

<?php
}
?>
});

Comment: I have updated my answer with respect to database end. Get unique records from database itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_unique

```
 $var= array_unique($product->get_available_variations());
```

Why don't you get unique records from database itself use `distinct` on the column

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
<?php
    $var= array_unique($product->get_available_variations());
    foreach ($var as $key => $test)
    {  $check=$test['display_price']; ?>

    jQuery('<p>'+<?php echo $check; ?> +'</p>').appendTo('.variation_buttons_wrapper');
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you,i am trying this is also ,But same issue i got a repeated values         53.95, 39.95, 29.95, 27.95, 53.95, 39.95, 29.95, 27.95.Please check what is error ..Can you know in jquery how to run foreach one time??

Comment: use .each(function(){ /*    */});

Comment: yes.i am using .each(function(){}.........this is all show values repeated

Answer (score 0):

```
use array_unique() function of php that avoid duplicate entries.

answer 2. 

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
<?php
$var= $product->get_available_variations();
$arr = array();
 foreach ($var as $key => $test)
{
if(!in_array($test['display_price'],$arr))  
{ 
  $check=$test['display_price'];
?>
 var check='<?php echo $check;?>';              

 jQuery('<p>'+check+'</p>').appendTo('.variation_buttons_wrapper');

 <?php

 $arr[]=$test['display_price'];
} 
}
 ?>


this will help.
```

Comment: yes this is also i tired..but no result again again show repeated values

Comment: then you need to do small code of line..adding in answer

Answer (score 0):

//  try this patch

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    <?php
    $var = array_unique($product->get_available_variations());
    foreach ($var as $key => $test)
    {
        $check = $test['display_price'];
    ?>
        var check = "<?php echo $check;?>";              

        jQuery('<p>'+check+'</p>').appendTo('.variation_buttons_wrapper');

    <?php  }  ?>

});

</script>
```

try also this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            <?php
            $var = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $product->get_available_variations())));
            foreach ($var as $key => $test)
            {
                $check = $test['display_price'];
            ?>
                var check = "<?php echo $check;?>";              
                jQuery('<p>'+check+'</p>').appendTo('.variation_buttons_wrapper');

            <?php  }  ?>

        });
 </script>
```

Comment: yes, i can tired .this time  53.95 is display 4 time.missing 39.95, 29.95, 27.95.

Comment: Any body here ..Please help me.I don't know .how to fix this issue.

Comment: @murugesh please print_r($var); and send me.

Comment: Array
           (
         [0] => Array
          (
        [variation_id] => 17885
        [variation_is_visible] => 1
        [variation_is_active] => 1
        [is_purchasable] => 1
        [display_price] => 53.95

Comment: this is $var= $product->get_available_variations();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($var); values.

Comment: @murugesh thats why its show only 53.95 because display_price is 53.95.  i think this is not complete array values because its show only one row.

Comment: yes its show 4 array values ..But this comment box only allowed 350 charcter. So i sented one data

Comment: you just show me display_price index values for all 4 rows.